# Histogram with percentage not shown correctly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have 3 dataframes of different sizes, but the data is around the same spread. I want to plot a histogram where bars are not stacked behind each other. but next to each other. But somehow the graph below shows as empty. I am using percentage to show the spread of values in bins across 3 data frames.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bins=[0.065,0.066,0.066867,0.06721653, 0.06756605, 0.06791558 ,0.06826511 ,0.06861463, 0.06896416 ,0.06931368 ,0.06966321 ,
          0.07001274 ,0.07036226, 0.07071179, 0.07106132]

heights_a, bins_a = np.histogram(data_a,density=True,bins=bins)
heights_b, bins_b = np.histogram(data_b, bins= bins, density=True)
heights_c, bins_c = np.histogram(data_c, bins= bins, density=True)

width = (bins[1] - bins[0])/3
percent_a = [i/sum(heights_a) for i in heights_a]
percent_b = [i/sum(heights_b) for i in heights_b]
percent_c = [i/sum(heights_c) for i in heights_c]


# Plot
plt.hist([percent_a,percent_b,percent_c],bins=bins)
```

for ref: values of percent a, b, c are below

```
percent_a: [0.0, 0.14461138635261822, 0.7135723695665084, 0.1332331586302625, 0.005661456252881448, 0.001252117554145005, 0.0004645085112166378, 0.00035005436997602294, 0.00022215624449490486, 0.00023561351825309235, 0.0002086862590241675, 6.732007408936779e-05, 6.05863332650809e-05, 6.05863332650809e-05]

percent_b: [0.0, 0.022353373799523353, 0.28872107539164565, 0.2832141014468122, 0.24881229833603277, 0.11762929879669072, 0.026817901548899136, 0.006551745201648785, 0.002257040090596458, 0.0011432973091484767, 0.0009715065217634725, 0.0005568550354752638, 0.0005746105647015661, 0.0003968959570619065]

percent_c: [0.0, 0.0017632461817612324, 0.2052342190616211, 0.204701164814267, 0.21966000802963298, 0.1954941169546308, 0.12414021698344926, 0.04017437572609526, 0.006155103753006311, 0.0010381122222360116, 0.0007998569581162712, 0.00045950544146869214, 0.0002609462416549537, 0.00011912763205987017]
```

and output is:
[image]

```
(array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]), array([0.065     , 0.066     , 0.066867  , 0.06721653, 0.06756605,
        0.06791558, 0.06826511, 0.06861463, 0.06896416, 0.06931368,
        0.06966321, 0.07001274, 0.07036226, 0.07071179, 0.07106132]),  <a list of 3 Lists of Patches objects>)
```

Comment: yes that is a typo. I have updated the code. problem still exists

Comment: `plt.hist` calculates the histogram and then plots. If you already have the percentages then you need to use `plt.bar` to actually plot a bar plot.